# iTextsharp multiline fields text not aligning with line

Tags: forms, pdf, itext

We have some pdf forms with multiline fields. When we are filling the data in those fields with itextsharp 5, the text is not aligning with the lines properly.
Is there any

[image: Multiline fields line alignment]

Here is my code - and I am sending flatten = true

```
   public static Stream FillPdf(Stream SourceFile, IDictionary<string, string> Values, bool flatten = false)
    {
        //Set Unethical reading to true to overcome owner password
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        //create PdfReader object to read the source file
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SourceFile);
        Stream output = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper stamper;
        if (flatten)
            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
        else
            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output, '\0', true);
        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;

        Values.ToList().ForEach(v => form.SetField(v.Key, v.Value ?? string.Empty));

        stamper.FormFlattening = flatten;

        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Please share the PDF in question, both with and without your fill-ins.

Comment: I have uploaded the file here..https://1drv.ms/b/s!Au_gZq25QyhrbPo1ud8nWN1FA4Y

Comment: I took a first look: Your PDF is a hybrid form, XFA and AcroForm, with a broken usage rights signature. In the XFA version text data are properly aligned, but in the AcroForm version they do not appear to be. As the dokument contains a broken usage right  signature, Adobe Reader only shows the latter, badly aligned version. I would try removing the usage rights signature completely when filling in the form.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. XFA forms can contain instructions how to fill in multi-line fields, in particular setting a line height, and Adobe Reader uses these information also to fill in the AcroForm appearance. iTextSharp, on the other hand, only knows the standard AcroForm way to fill in information (iTextSharp only partially supports XFA). Thus, outputs differ. As the XFA specification is not part of the PDF specification and in particular there is no indication AcroForm filling has to follow XFA instructions, that is completely ok.

Comment: There is a `XfaWorker` in the iText product selection, you might want to try whether that worker gets along with your form.

Comment: Thanks @mkl . The XFAWorker is taking care of these properly.